# Passing NSArray makes array empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, segue

i'm trying to pass an array from a view to another using the PrepareForSegue method.
In the first view i got a button called "Submit" that, if pressed, reads a textView and store the text in a NSArray, and then should pass this array to another view (push segue), but when the array arrives is empty. 
Here is the code

```
//.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *words;


//.m

- (IBAction)Submit:(id)sender{
    //read textView
    _words = [self.myTextView.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    //if Submit is pressed go to SecondViewController
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"secondSegue"]) {
        SecondViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.array = _words;
    }
}
```

So here is the code of the SecondViewController that receives the array

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self Calculate];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)Calculate
{
    int size = [array count];
    NSLog(@"size is %d",size);
}
```

the log always says "size is 0".
Did i make some mistake?
Could it be that the Segue happens before i can read the TextView and fill the array so it's always empty?
thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I tried to NSLog the Submit action and i discovered that the program never accesses to it, so it never reads! (p.s. yes i connected the button)
So the segue happens before the Submit action
How can i solve? can i copy the PrepareForSegue code in the Submit action?

Comment: You'll get the "size is 0" response when `array` is nil.

Comment: Are you sure the array is empty and not nil?

Comment: The usual reason for a nil property in this general scenario is setting the property in a different instance of the class from the one that is later referenced.

Comment: i tried to NSLog after the read of the textView in the Submit method but the log never appears, so i think that the program never goes through it and skip to the next view before anything can happen!

Comment: I recreated what I could gather from your post and the submit: gets called before prepareForSegue:, which results in the array count working in SecondViewController. It seems you need to fix the button that submits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try copying the array when you send it, Could be getting freed also are you sure -`(IBAction)submit`.. is being called?

Also the submit button I assume has the action that performs the segue . I'm not sure on the order of execution. Try calling the method Submit from prepare for segue and not from the button. That way you can guarantee it is being called first.

Comment: Yes it's connected to the only button in the view. I think the problem is that it skips to the next view before accessing to this action, so the array is empty when reaches the new view!But i don't know how to solve

Comment: @ObiWanKeNerd Is the array nil or just empty?

Comment: Also the submit button I assume has the action that performs the segue . I'm not sure on the order of execution. Try calling the method Submit from prepare for segue and not from the button. That way you can guarantee it is being called first.

Comment: i think it's nil because it's never filled as the Submit action where i read it never happens

Comment: you are a genius it worked!!! I copied the Submit action code in the PrepareForSegue Method

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the @synthesize, the compiler will automatically synthesize
   the ivar to be _words
2. Use self.words when assigning and accessing the 'words' array. This ensures the ivar gets set properly as well, if you plan to refer to it directly (which you won't in most cases).

Your problem is that @synthesize creates an ivar called 'words', not '_words'.

Comment: Yes i'm sorry i wrote it wrong but i didn't synthesized it! it gives me no error just continue passing an empty array. I'll edit!
Now it's the right code, the @synthesize i wrote was from the SecondView to access the data in the method Calculate

Comment: @ObiWanKeNerd How did you declare 'array' in SecondViewController?

Comment: `//.h @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *array;` 
and 
`//.m @synthesize array;`